# What are the other php password encryption functions other than md5?

Tags: encryption, passwords

I have been looking around the internet alot about how to make a login page for a website, and came across the md5 function for password encryption, and also salts for passwords. I looked up md5 and found quite a few pages that said md5 isn't secure, and hackers could crack it. What are the other encryption functions in php?

Comment: Have a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4795385/how-do-you-use-bcrypt-for-hashing-passwords-in-php) for information on bcrypt.

Comment: Hackers can crack "anything".  Used properly, MD5 is more than you (probably) need.

Comment: @Madbreaks Sheesh. What kind of advice is that? No, hackers cannot crack "\"anything\"".

Comment: First of all, MD5 is *NOT* an encryption algorithm. It's a hash algorithm. Secondly, A pizza isn't a grilled cheese sandwich, and a grilled cheese sandwich isn't a pizza even though both contain copious amounts of cheese; similarly, password hashing and password encryption are two very different things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heres a list of hashing functions built in with PHP

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.hash-algos.php